# Double-nested Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have Steps which belong to Procedures:

```
map.resources :procedures, :has_many => :steps
```

And this works fine for me, I get URLs that look like /procedures/3/steps/5.

However, suppose I wanted to add one more layer, Figures that belong to steps, to get this: /procedures/3/steps/5/figures/1

That being a monster of a URL aside, how exactly would I do the routing for this?

**Edit**: Maybe I shouldn't put that aside, **should** I do this? Figures are simply containers for images which I will display in the Steps, so it's not like the user will actually "visit" any Figure, I just need to fetch the images from the Figures.

Comment: Just so you know, URI representations are orthogonal to REST. Furthermore, if you have a different URI for a subset of the same resource (and using the same media type) then you're probably violating a constraint of REST. For figures that belong to steps, something along the lines of /figures/1?step=5 might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.resources :procedures do |procedure|
  procedure.resources :steps do |step|
    step.resources :figures
  end
end
```

If you need routes like /figures/ then use:

```
map.resources :procedures, :shallow => true do |procedure|
  procedure.resources :steps do |step|
    step.resources :figures
  end
end
```

In your views it's something like:

```
<%= link_to "Figure", figure_url(@procedure, @step, @figure) -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) explains it better than I can off the top of my head.  Basically, you can use the [:name_prefix option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) when defining your routes to acheive what you're looking for.

Comment: According to that article I should simply not do this, and do something like this instead:  map.resources :steps, :has_many => :figures.

However, suppose that the user will never actually go to the Figure, but the Figures will simply be used by Steps. Should I still separate it out or is it okay to leave it as a massive double-nested thing?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I think you're right: you won't ever need to route to the figures... and you never want to unnecessarily over-complicate your routes.

It sounds like the furthest you'll go will be the Show action for your steps... and you'll just ask ActiveRecord for the list of figures for that step. That is, you'll have

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :figures
end
```

and

```
class Figure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
  has_many :images #perhaps?
end
```

but for routing you only need to care about resources that will be RESTfully requested - in this case it looks like your `procedures`, and their associated `steps`. The route you listed in the question looks spot-on to me!